# Create simple array from complex array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the following two arrays:

**Array One**

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 36 [name] => Fractions [slug] => fractions-cat [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 36 [taxonomy] => emp_unit_name [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 11 [filter] => raw [term_order] => 0 ) 
        [1] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 38 [name] => Geometry [slug] => geometry [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 38 [taxonomy] => emp_unit_name [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 2 [filter] => raw [term_order] => 0 ) 
      )
```

**Array Two**

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 36 [name] => Fractions [slug] => fractions-cat [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 36 [taxonomy] => emp_unit_name [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 11 [filter] => raw [term_order] => 0 ) )
```

I'm trying to compare the two arrays to find if there are any matches for the [term_id] values as such:

```
$match = array_intersect($array_one_ids, $array_two_ids);
if( count($match) > 0) {  echo 'we have a match!';  }
```

My question is, how can I create arrays (defined by `$array_one_ids` and `$array_two_ids`) of just the `term_id` values in each of the above arrays such that `$array_one_ids` would = `array(36, 38)` and `$array_two_ids` would = `array(36)`?

Comment: I added an answer that I think will work for you. This looks like wordpress stuff, and there may be a neater way of doing it in wordpress, but that isn't my area of expertise so I can't advise there. But _maybe_ if you show how you're getting these two arrays and add a wordpress tag, you could get a better answer based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_column` on each of the input arrays to convert them to arrays of `term_id`.

```
$match = array_intersect(
    array_column($arrayOne, 'term_id'),
    array_column($arrayTwo, 'term_id')
);
```

For older PHP versions where `array_column` doesn't handle arrays of objects, you can use `array_map` to extract that property.

```
$match = array_intersect(
    array_map(function($term) { return $term->term_id; }, $arrayOne),
    array_map(function($term) { return $term->term_id; }, $arrayTwo)
);
```

Also, you don't have to count `$match` to check the result, as an array evaluates to `true` or `false` in an if condition depending on whether it's empty. ([See "converting to boolean"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).)

```
if ($match) {  echo 'we have a match!';  }
```

Comment: In your example, I'm getting an empty array with: print_r(array_column($user_terms, 'term_id'))

Comment: Hmm, what's your PHP version? `array_column` won't work on arrays of objects in older versions (before 7)

Comment: @scmccarthy22 I added a different method that should work if you're still on PHP 5.

Comment: Thanks @Don't Panic - this worked well. Other Wordpress-specific answers worked as well, but checking this as the best answer since I tagged the question as just "php" ... Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the whole `WP_Term` object, you can add a `fields` parameter to your query when you retrieve it to only retrieve the ids of the terms.

For example:

```
$queryOne = new WP_Term_Query(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'emp_unit_name',
     ... // The other args of your query,
    'fields' => 'ids'
));
```

Then you can access the ids (`$query->terms`):

```
array(36, 38);
```

Once you have both queries, you could do:

```
$match = array_intersect($queryOne->terms, $queryTwo->terms);
```

However, if you need the whole object, you can do it like [@Don't Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338493/5556440)'s answer.